# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS TWebModule Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I have the Delphi Web service, using TWebModule..
But, i have problem with HTTP/HTPPS.
I can't redirect request http to https.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy. In **`WebModuleUnit`** type the following:

```
procedure TWebModule1.WebModule1DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject;
    Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Request.QueryFields.Values['proto'] = 'http' then
    if Request.QueryFields.Values['target'] <> '' then
      Response.SendRedirect('https://' + Request.QueryFields.Values['target'])
    else
      Response.Content := '<HTML><BODY>Invalid URI</BODY></HTML>';
  Response.Content :=
    '<html>' +
    '<head><title>DataSnap Server</title></head>' +
    '<body>DataSnap Server</body>' +
    '</html>';
end;
```